# Corebluetooth error

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am totally stuck on why this code works on iOS 10 but not iOS 11

```
let bytes: [UInt8] = [0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0xC0, 0x00, 0x00]
let data = Data(bytes: bytes)
connectedPeripheral?.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
```

On iOS 10 when I write the command, I get a response, but on iOS 11 I write the command I don't get a response and it hangs. Then the app tells me I am disconnected from the device.

Any tip would be helpful.

Comment: You'll need to provide more than just these 3 lines of code. Provide the complete file, or at least relevant parts of it. Also, try printing out the value of connectedPeripheral and characteristic, they might be empty.

Comment: @Armin These are the relevant parts. I tried printing the value of the connectedPeripheral and characteristic they were all there. It works on iOS 10 and not iOS 11. That's the only variable that changed (other than time). Try this for yourself and you'll see what I mean.